# BLE kotlin .discoverServices() doesn't find any service

Tags: kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I implemented two different solution to discover service on my BLE device. One use a handler then return what .discoverService have found, the other one is really similar but give the size of the service discovered list that is always 0. I tried it with my realme buds 2 as test and some other device publically visible. The result is always 0. What can the problem be?

```
Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                        var temp = bluetoothGatt?.discoverServices()
                        addGlog("discordservice() returned ${temp.toString()}")
                    }

                    addGlog("handler discover service reached an end")
                    val gattServices: List<BluetoothGattService> = gatt.getServices()
                    addGlog("Services count: " + gattServices.size)

                    for (gattService in gattServices) {
                        val serviceUUID = gattService.uuid.toString()
                        addGlog("Service uuid $serviceUUID")
                    }
```

edit: AddGlog is a simple log function to print results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer: The code is not wrong but it take some time to discover those services so i put this code in a button. In this way there is 3-4 second of time between connecting with the device and make a discoveryservice operation. So a button make the conneting operations and another one the service discovery operations. I am sorry if my answer is pretty lame but I am still a noob on this topic